# python map unexpected result

Tags: python, dictionary

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = map(int, input().split())
    a = max([x for x in arr if x != max(arr)])
    print(a)
```

sample input: `1 2 3 4 5`

goal here is to find second greatest number

`type(max(arr))` is integer,
each element type in `arr` when looping is integer,
so why output isnt 4? This works perfectly only when I do `arr = list(arr)` but I want to know why wouldnt it work without it?

Comment: In addition to what's said in the answers, a list comprehension like `[int(x) for x in inp.split()]` is almost always a better choice than `map`.

Comment: Better solutions: [Get the second largest number in a list in linear time](/q/16225677/4518341)

Comment: @gog: When the mapping function is a built-in that already does what you need, there's no reason to prefer a listcomp over `map` (for built-ins implemented in C, the `map` will be slightly faster on a per-item basis, and shorter, and when you don't need the result as a `list` anyway, you're just iterating it once, lower latency and higher memory efficiency).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: `map` has its uses, but this is not one of them.

Comment: @gog: There's nothing inherently terrible about using `list(map(int, input().split()))` (or `[*map(int, input().split())]`) instead of `[int(x) for x in input().split()]`. `map` is a strictly bad idea if you need a `lambda` to use it (where a listcomp or genexpr could inline it and avoid the function call entirely), but there's *nothing* wrong with `map` here.

Comment: "I value readability and usefulness for real code. There are some places where map() and filter() make sense, and for other places Python has list comprehensions" -- https://developers.slashdot.org/story/13/08/25/2115204/interviews-guido-van-rossum-answers-your-questions

Answer (score 2):

`map` returns an iterator so it can only be consumed once. The first call to `max(arr)` in the first iteration already consumes it for every subsequent iteration.

If you want the second largest number, just sort the array and get the second (or second-to-last, depending on how you order). This will also give you a O(nlogn) solution instead of the (potentially) O(n^2) solution that you have attempted to write.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `arr` is an iterator, and you can only go through an iterator once.

You start off with `[x for x in arr...]` and x gets the value `1`.  You then take `max(arr)`, and that's going to see the item 2, 3, 4, 5 and then use all of them up.  It will return `5`, but now the iterator is empty.  Your outer `[...]` now sees that there are no more elements to look at, and returns max(1) = 1.